# can't automate login with Python and Selenium (error: element not found on website)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

so yeah.. the problem is pretty obvious: the link is opened, but nothing happens
and it throws the error that the element is not found but the site is fully loaded so I don't see the reason

I have tried following a tutorial and used the code shown there and it did not work even there it was fine ( I had the same error)
any piece of advice is welcome and appreciated!!

```
the error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Next\PycharmProjects\igtool\main.py", line 13, in <module>
        browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('main_frame'))
      File "C:\Users\Next\PycharmProjects\igtool\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
        return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
      File "C:\Users\Next\PycharmProjects\igtool\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
        return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
      File "C:\Users\Next\PycharmProjects\igtool\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Users\Next\PycharmProjects\igtool\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="main_frame"]"}

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Next\PycharmProjects\igtool\main.py", line 19, in <module>
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, input_u_xpath))).send_keys("user4248user")
      File "C:\Users\Next\PycharmProjects\igtool\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 



 from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.get('<some url>')

sleep(8)
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('main_frame'))

# Find the element by applying explicit wait on it and then click on it
input_u_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input'
input_p_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/label/input"

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, input_u_xpath))).send_keys("<username>")
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, input_p_xpath))).send_keys("<password>")
# username_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
#   "c")
# password_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
#    "")
login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button")
login_button.click()
sleep(5)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: I need a clarification. What element is not being found? The username and password buttons?

Comment: It's the iframe not being found can you include the iframe html element.

Comment: nothing is found.. it tries to find the first element I have put in my code and runs into error then breaks

Comment: actually I am not sure how to get the frame. I supposed it it main

Comment: Actually I have solved it by updating to the latest python version